# Map performance issue

Tags: c++, performance, dictionary

If someone could help me out, I'm completely out of ideas.

So I have this code (it's a very simplified version of my code):

```
while(readNewFile())
{
    while(getNewStructFromFile())
    {
        unsigned long starttime = GetTickCount();
        customerData.fillFromBinaryData(structPointer);
        cout<< GetTickCount() - starttime;

        aMap.insert(pair<int,string>(customerData.phoneNumber,""));
    }

    // Ouptut all data

    aMap.clear();
}
```

Basically, it just reads records from a binary file. `customerData` get's the data and fills its variables with data from it. Then, it inserts the phone number into a map (for debugging I am really just inserting an int and an empty string).

The problem is, that after a short while this program gets very slow; if I comment out the map insert the program runs OK without problems with a constant execution time per file. If I use the map insertion, after a few files, the program again goes very slow (from 8 - 10 seconds to 1 minute or more).
But debugging with `GetTickCount()`, it shows me that the delay happens in `customerData.fillFromBinaryData` (at first 0ms, and then it jumps to 30-40 ms (for filling out the class variables)). But if I comment this simple map insertion, there is no delay in filling the object with data! Where is the logic in that?
Could someone give me a hint, I am out of ideas. Sorry if this question is not a really good one.

I tried different types of maps, but again, it shows me that the delay is not in the map insertion.

**Edit/Possible solution:**

In case someone has similar issues, I installed VS2015, and the delay using maps is gone! I am not sure how this is related, but Hurray!

Comment: You are printing all the data in every loop? The data gets bigger each time ....

Comment: I simply cannot be the only person remotely curious why this question is tagged `asn.1`, considering there is absolutely no mention of it whatsoever in the question body.

Comment: I output once per file, and I clear the map after this, why would get it bigger ? customerData is just one customer record, each time it gets a new value. I am actually readding from an asn file :) I am not sure why I added the tag...

Comment: You know you can write `aMap[customerData.phoneNumber] = "";` right?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I need just the first record with the same phone number, that's why I'm using insert. I tried the other way, still, there is no difference in performance. Inserting in a map makes the object behave poorly and I cannot find a logical reason for that !

Comment: What is customerData (is phoneNumber a property or just an int?) and what does fillFromBinaryData do?

Comment: @o_weisman phoneNumber is just an int. fillFromBinaryData gets a pointer to a struct filled with data, and converts it to needed format. We use a toolkit to help read binary files, but still I cannot understand, how inserting into a map decrease performance in any of those, without the map insertion it works perfectly. Anyway thanks guys for your comments, you are awesome :) I won't give up )

Comment: @o_weisman Since when does C++ have properties?

Comment: @MattMcNabb or even `aMap[customerData.phoneNumber];`.

Comment: Try to do something else, just to "use" the phone number. For example, initialize a variable `x` to zero, and instead of `map.insert(...)` write `x += customerData.phoneNumber`. Does it affect the performance of your program?

If it does affect the performance, then the problem is indeed in the `fillFromBinaryData` method, and when you do not insert to the map, a compiler optimization kicks in. 

If it does not affect the performance, then we should look into why the map works slowly.

Comment: How many records are you inserting into the map?

Comment: Could you show the source code of `customerData.fillFromBinaryData` ?

Comment: @Meixner about 3500 per file.

Comment: Why not use a profiler to find the performance bottleneck? It tells you how many times your functions are called and how much time is taken by them respectively taken by child functions.

Comment: @Meixner thanks for a great sugestion, I didn't knew of such a thing :D But using VS2010 express right now :( Will install soon the VS2013, will try then if I won't solve this by then.

Answer (score 1):

It might happen, that if a map grows very big, you have a problem with memory management and `fillFromBinaryData` requires some memory allocation which is now slower. Due to a memory fragmentation maybe?

I would suggest to try some libraries for this specific purpose. However, I forgot how they are called. I just know that there is one available from Google, "jemalloc" or something similar.

The main point of a custom memory pool is that you can allocate memory once as a big bunch, and use it only in a scope of your app with custom allocators.

One more thing is maybe to stop to use a map and use the unordered map instead. Change the time complexity for insertion from O(logn) to O(1) with a perfect hash function, since for you, is a phone number.

- It is called jemalloc and it is not from Google. :)

Comment: Well the first few files the map goes ok, how can this be explained ? I call clear() after each file, so the map should start again from 0, it's not like it's still growing ? And I use unordered map and reserve 4000 elements, a file has about 3500 records.

Comment: Then it might be a fragmentation issue. Check what jemalloc does. Otherwise I don't know what it might be. I would suggest then to run your app with valgrind --tool=callgrind or something similar.